# Is there a way to print random values

Tags: r

In R programming, can we print random values at any given point. For example we have `unique(iris$Species)` showing 3 categories. But Can we print any one category at any given point of time.

Comment: Have a look at `?sample()`

Comment: @Sotos you do not need the brackets ?sample

Comment: @DimitriosZacharatos details...it still works...

Comment: @Sotos yes it does, I did not know you could put brackets and still work I tested it just now

Answer (score 1):

Use `sample()` from base R

```
sample(unique(iris$Species),1)
```

Comment: why not sample(iris$Species,size=1), it would still output one thing

Comment: It would indeed, but wouldn't the different occurrence of categories in the data, make some categories more likely than others to be sampled ?

Comment: Hi all thanks for the time. I run this ````sample(unique(iris$Species),1)````. But i get only 1 category all the time

Comment: It works as expected for me. The only reason I can think of, for you getting the same result over and over again, is that you pre filtered the dataset and it only has one level to choose from. What `Levels: setosa versicolor virginica` does it show you when you run it ?